# Update display name of a MultiViewElement's TopComponent

Tags: netbeans-platform

Is there a way to update the `TopComponent`'s display name that contains `MultiViewElement`s for a specific `DataObject`?

Here's the case : I register a new file type with specific mime and tell it to use Multiview. Next I implement some MultiViewElement for that mime. The default `EditorSupport` will handle the open/edit, such that when I double click the DataObject's `Node` on project explorer, a TopComponent with my Multiviews will appear on editor mode.

The problem appears when I want to rename the file, using "Rename" context menu from the DO's Node. The Node's display name will be updated successfully, as well as the file name (on disk). But

1. If the TC for that node is *not yet opened*, next time we open the TC, its display name will be displayed correctly. No problem occurs.
2. If the TC for that node is already opened but NOT activated (we're currently activated another TC on editor), the TC's display name will not be updated until we activate the TC.
3. If the TC for that node is already *opened and activated*, I have to activate another TC first, then select the first TC to update its display name.

Having the access, I will override `MultiDataObject.handleRename(String name)` and handle the TC's display name there.

Extra : This access to the TC's display name will also be useful in informing the user that corresponding DO is modified by styling it **boldface**.

Thanks